# Perl calling subroutine with leading '&'

Tags: perl, subroutine, ampersand

Every now and then I see Perl scripts where subroutines are called with a leading '&'.
Is this legacy, or does it give any benefit? 
As calling the subroutine without the ampersand sign works as well.

```
sub mysub {
        print "mysub\n"; 

}

mysub;
&mysub;
```

Thx/Hermann

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-the-difference-between-calling-a-function-as-%26foo-and-foo()%3f

Comment: @Quentin I think you're referring to [goto](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling with `&` is generally a code smell that somebody doesn't know what they're doing and are in a Perl4 mindset. In your specific example, it works exactly the same. However, calling with `&` disables function prototypes, so advanced users may use it in certain circumstances. You should expect to see a comment *why* next to the call in that case.

Comment: *Perl4 mindset.* possibly aquired by learning by googling and picking up bad examples

Comment: Thanks a lot it is clear to me now. In my particular case the real subroutine had a prototype or even empty prototype (don't know how to say): sub mysub() { ... }. That works only if you disable function prototypes with &.

Comment: See the parenthesis next to mysub(). Calling this subroutine with () prototype works only if you disable function prototypes with & like &mysub;

Comment: Actually, `mysub;` and `&mysub;` are not exactly the same. The latter is equivalent to `&mysub(@_)`, not `&mysub()`.