# How to know if perl subroutine takes parameters

Tags: perl, parameters, subroutine

I'm quite new to perl and I can't seem to find any information on how one would know if a subroutine takes a parameter.

In other languages (e.g python, java, etc), it is very clear, a method/function usually looks like this:

```
    def my_func(arg1, arg2):
        # do something
```

But in perl, it's simply:

```
    sub my_func {
        my params = @_;
        # do something
    }
```

But I've seen examples where **my params = @_** isn't even included, but the subroutine is called  and passed an argument.

e.g

```
    sub my_func {
        my $self = shift;
        my $fieldstr = 'tbl'.$self->db_func.'*,';
        my $sql = "SELECT $fieldstr FROM tbl".$self->db_func.'WHERE'.$self->...;

        my $sth = $self->other_func->my_func($sql) or return undef;
    }
```

So I was wondering if there is some sort of guideline to know if a subroutine takes a parameter(s)?

Comment: Related: [Perl subroutine arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234209/perl-subroutine-arguments)

Comment: Also relevant: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures

Comment: `shift` inside a sub is the same as `shift(@_)`.

Comment: Typically, documentation of whatever sub or method should indicate what the arguments are.  (Not trying to be snarky.)

Comment: Since you're going to be writing documentation *anyway* (as you mentioned in a comment on a now-deleted answer), please do your successor(s) a favor and add [POD](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=252477) to the source files you examine.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know Perl at all, but are required to document some Perl code? There is *no way* to know what a Perl subroutine expects in its parameter list with *reading and understanding the code*.

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234780/622310).

Perl is hyper-flexible, in that a subroutine can simply ignore excess parameters, provide defaults for missing ones, or `die` if the parameters aren't *exactly* what is expected.

Perl's author, [Larry Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall), is a linguist, and the rationale behind this is that subroutines behave like imperative verbs; so just as you could say *"fetch the wood"*, *"fetch the wood from behind the shed"*, or *"fetch the wood from behind the shed using the tractor"*, you can equally say

```
fetch($wood)
fetch($wood, $shed)
fetch($wood, $shed, $tractor)
```

or even

```
fetch($wood, {from => 'shed', using => 'tractor'})
```

and it is up to the subroutine to work out what is required.

Subroutine prototypes should be avoided, as they have side-effects that change the behaviour of the code in ways that aren't obvious. They are intended only for writing additional language constructs; a good example is [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny).

Comment: But I need to know of a way to determine even needs a parameter. I've mentioned in one of my comments, that I'm making a system design document. So in order to accurately document each function, I would need to know while I'm looking at a specific func, if it takes a parameter. Otherwise, I'd have to keep going back to the same file and editing it each time I find that it's being called/passed an argument.

Comment: He's asking how to identify the parameters of a function, not how to enforce/validate them.

Comment: @yob-v-u Again, *all* subroutines take *as many arguments* as you give it. There is nothing in the definition of a subroutine that specifies how many arguments it should be given when called, because Perl does not enforce any thing like that. Each subroutine simply receives a list, stored in the local array `@_`, of arguments that were passed on the command line.

Comment: @yob-v-u: Re *"I've mentioned in one of my comments, that I'm making a system design document"*, if that is significant to youir question then you should *edit your question* to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments are passed in `@_`, so you'd need to look for uses of `@_`. For example,

- `my ($x, $y) = @_;`
- `shift` in a sub is the same as `shift(@_)`
- `$_[$i]`
- `&f` (but not `&f()`), as in `sub log_warn { unshift @_, 'warn'; &log }`

As a sub writer, you should use these as near the top of the sub as possible to make them obvious. The last two are usually used as optimizations or to have by-reference parameters.

Comment: You said I need to look for uses of @_. But @_ isn't included in the function

Comment: Not all uses of `@_` require `@_` to be present. Read the rest of my answer, where I list three other ways `@_` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for a subroutine call are contained in the array [`@_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG).

Two important functions for array manipulation are [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) and [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html). Suppose you have a list (1, 2, 3, 4). 
`shift` removes a value from the left side of the list and returns it.

```
my @list = ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

my $value = shift @list;

print "$value\n";    # will print "1"
print "@list\n";     # will print "2 3 4"
```

`pop` does the same thing from the right side instead of the left:

```
my @list = ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

my $value = pop @list;

print "$value\n";    # will print "4"
print "@list\n";     # will print "1 2 3"
```

When used inside a subroutine, `pop` and `shift` will use the `@_` array by default:

```
some_function( 'James', 99 );    #these 2 arguments will be passed to the function in "@_"

sub some_function {
    my $name = shift;             #remove 'James' from list @_ and store it in $name
    my $age  = shift;             #remove 99 from list @_ and store it in $age
    print "Your name is $name and your age is $age\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you please restate your question at the top of your examples? It's unclear what you're asking as it's written.

Comment: @JasonD Nothing is being asked because this is an answer, not a question.

Comment: Please don't call functions with the `&` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21908568/1137055))